# Redux - dispatch async action when selector fails

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, action, selector

I have the following connected component:

```
const selectFullNameById = (state, id) =>
{
    const user = state.domain.people.values.find(u => u.id === id)
    return `${user.lastName} ${user.firstName}`
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

    const files = ownProps.files.map(f => ({
        ...f,
        fullName: selectFullNameById(state, f.creatorId)
    }))

    return {
        ...ownProps,
        files
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Uploader)
```

The connected component receives an array with object literals as a Prop called files. Each object literal has a creatorId value, I want to pass to my presentational component the full name of this person, so I use a selector "selectFullNameById", to get these values. This works when this person is actually available in the global state.

But it could be that this person object literal is not yet present in the global state, and so a fetch should be done to the server to check what his name is. So I have an async action creator to do the lookup. But I don't know how to dispatch this from the selector.

Comment: Use onChange event from your selector to fire the action. Then in action first check if your store has the name already, otherwise go for a server fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
//1. create a default state for a person:

const DEFAULT_PERSON = { 
  id: -1,
  fullName: 'n/a',
  …
} //some useful stuff

//2. modify electFullNameById to

const selectFullNameById = (state, id) => {
  const user = state.domain.people.values.find(u => u.id === id) || null;
  //return default data, if user does not exist
  return (user === null) ?
    Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_PERSON).fullName :
    `${user.lastName} ${user.firstName}`
}

//3. refactor mapStateToProps to:

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

  const files = ownProps.files.map(f => ({
      ...f,
      fullName: selectFullNameById(state, f.creatorId)
  }))

  //no need to add the ownProps here
  return { files }
}
```

So the basic Idea is: Create some useful default data, which is used in case the user is not found. This way, you wont get any »undefined« error on the following usage of the data.

To dispatch an async action if a user if undefined can be added like so (assuming you are using redux thunk and fetch):

```
const loadUser = uid => dispatch => fetch(`${url}/${uid}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => dispatch({
    type: 'user/loaded',
    payload: { user: json }
  }));

const YourComponent = ({ users, loadUser}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {
      user.map(user => {
        if (!user loaded) loadUser(user.id);
        return (<some>html based on default data</html>)
      })
    }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can dispatch the action right at rendering time since this action is async and so the re-rendering of the component wont be called right away, what would lead to recursion. If there are many users which have to be loaded it might be a good idea to filter them out and load them at once.

Comment: If I follow your solution to fire the async request I would have to do this in every component that uses the users name. I don't consider this to be a viable solution.

Comment: Well: 1. You did not say that there are a couple of components using the user data. 2. You asked for how to do an async request in that situation and that is what I have answered. The Problem you have is that your data is not consistent at rendering time. It would be much easier for the overall process, if you just fix that BEFORE you start to render anything. Easiest thing would be, to do that within the action that initially fetches the user data, if that data is already present on »page load«, I would recommend to pre-process that at startup.

Comment: I can't prefetch a list of 30 000 users on startup. If I could put all the data immediately in my store, I wouldn't need to ask this question. What do you mean by "my data is not consistent"?

Comment: Also that is a common problem and there are plenty of solutions out there. One is paginations, another infinite scroll. If you have so many items in the list, you need a way to query only parts of them. "But it could be that this person object literal is not yet present in the global state", that is what I am referring to not consistent. Some part of the data is there, but not everything. Anyway: If you have a proper REST Api for that entity, you would not have the problem and your view client can easily be coded in a way that it consumes the items chunk by chunk.

Comment: "One is paginations, another infinite scroll. If you have so many items in the list, you need a way to query only parts of them." I'm not talking about rendering this list, I'm talking about querying it. I have a proper REST Api to get this entity. What I'm asking is what is the best way to structure my JS code to dispatch an action to fetch this entity from my REST API when this entity is not present in my store.

Comment: Well, the place to do that should be in the action. Give it two parameters, start and offset to define which item to pull from the server. Depending on how that whole thing should work, you need to trigger that action, either by click or scroll position or some else…

Comment: Yes, but can I trigger the action when I do a select on my store and notice it's not there? How do I get access to the dispatch function in mapStateToProps to achieve this?
Right now I imported the store directly in my selector module to be able to dispatch from there, but this makes my selectors impure.

Comment: Would be worth to continue that in chat. Since it bloats the comments here. Can you join that room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149965/question-45210452

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a similar solution and want to know if you resolved this with middleware as discussed in chat? I'm going to go figure out the middleware, but it would help me (and probably others) if the answer was updated and subsequently marked correct or upvoted. Thanks!